# Mysql query for distinct count based on a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've situation in which I want to find out the occurrence of items in a particular column without grouping the elements. Here's the situation.

**User Table :**

```
UserID     :     Name
  1              User1
  2              User2
```

**Tags :**

```
TagID      :     Tag 
  1              Tag1  
  2              Tag2  
  3              Tag3
```

**UserTags :**

```
 UserID     :    TagID
    1             1
    1             2
    2             3
```

Now the following query returns.

```
select ut.tagid
     ,t.tag,ut.userid
from tags t
inner join usertags ut on ut.tagID=t.tagid
order by userid
```

**Result:**

```
 TagID    :   Tag     :  UserID
   1          Tag1         1
   2          Tag2         1
   3          Tag3         2
```

Which is correct. I just want to add one more column to this result set such that it tells me the distinct count of `UserID` in the result set. So that my result set looks like this.

**Required Result Set :**

```
 TagID    :   Tag     :  UserID  :  UserIDoccurrence
   1          Tag1         1             2
   2          Tag2         1             2
   3          Tag3         2             1
```

As you can see. Since user with `userID = 1` has two results. I got `2` in the `UserIDOccurrence` column and 1 for UserID 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches.  This uses a correlated subquery:

```
select ut.tagid, t.tag, ut.userid,
       (select count(*) from usertags ut2 where ut2.userid = ut.userid) as totalcount
from tags t inner join
     usertags ut
     on ut.tagID = t.tagid
order by userid;
```